# How to download symfony 2.8 without vendors?

Tags: php, symfony

How can I download symfony in version 2.8 without vendors? 
I don't want to use composer, where is link for this version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply download/clone it from GitHub:

https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/tree/2.8

But I am not sure, how you want to use it, without vendors and without composer.